# Django how to append current logged in user to request.data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How do I append current logged in user to request.data when making post call to create a new chat. I tried append it to the request.data but its a querydict and immutable
// models.py

```
class ChatLog(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
participants = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='chatlogs')

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)


class Message(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
chat_log = models.ForeignKey(ChatLog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages')
sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sentmessages')
body = models.TextField()
is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created']
```

// views.py

```
class ChatList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
serializer_class = ChatSerializer
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user.profile
    return user.chatlogs.all()

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = ChatSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: You should be able to access user by `request.user`

Comment: Thank you. I did that but how do i append it to the request.data.

Comment: Is it really necessary to do that? You just seem to be creating a chat message in your view.  But you could make a new list. `data = [request.user] + list(request.data)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListCreateAPIView` specifically has [the `perform_create` method you can override](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users). By default it just does:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()
```

You can override that to [add additional data to the `serializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save) for example:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(sender=self.request.user)
```

Get rid of your `post` method, you're just overriding and repeating the automagic for which you're using generic views in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. I tried something like this  serializer.save(sender=self.request.user) but participants is a manytomanyfield and this doesnt work

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your goal is, but this is roughly how to go about it. You want to add what to what exactly?

Comment: say I want to create a new chat with a user. I make a post api call to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/chat/. The participants field is required. My goal is to autofill the current logged in user as one of the participants.

Comment: `serializer.save(participants=[self.request.user])` then…?

Comment: I did this for the other views but doesnt work for this one because I also need to add the participants coming from request.data

Comment: You might need to override and customise your serialiser's [`create` and/or `save` methods](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior) then. It would help if you provided more information in the question and focused more on this specific aspect.

Comment: ''' def perform_create(self, serializer):
  serializer.save(participants=[self.request.user.profile]+[self.request.data['participants']])''' This works for me. Thank you